# Run Modal after async call made

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

I am new to Swift Mac App development, I am having troubling going from a login window to showing the main window after a login URLRequest, and making another URLRequest in the new main window. If I just go from one window without making the login URLRequest, it works fine.

```
func loadMainView() {

    self.view.window?.close()

    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! NSWindowController

    if let mainWindow = mainWindowController.window {

        let application1 = NSApplication.shared()
        application1.runModal(for: mainWindow)
    }
}

func tryLogin(_ username: String, password: String ) {

    Staff.login(username: self.username.stringValue, password: self.password.stringValue) { (completed, result, staff) in
         // DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if completed {

            if result == .Success && staff != nil {

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                   self.loadMainView()
                })
            } else {

                self.dialogOKCancel(message: "Error", text: "Your credentials are incorrect")
            }

        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}

HTTPSConnection.httpGetRequestURL(token: token, url: digialOceanURL, mainKey: mainKeyVal) { ( complete, results) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if complete {

            }
        }

    }
```

I have tried calling the self.loadMainView() without the execute, but still not luck.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: so you have some error or what do you mean with "no luck"

Comment: sorry, the second URLRequest in the main window does not come out of the background thread.

Comment: we need to se the code, you did not show anything, this code not doing anything serious

Comment: show all the code you are talking about, then we will know where is a mistake because in overal this should work, it is normal flow

Comment: i have updated the question code snippet, see above, once the see.loadMainView() function gets called, the mainWindow does appear, but any url request inside the new window does not come out of the background thread

Comment: there is no code where you are calling request in second view

Comment: the second request works fine if the first window login request is not executed

Comment: Why do you call `runModal` and why async?

Comment: The runModal runs the window, and why async is mainly due to a tutorial from Raywenderlich, i was following. The application first displays a login window, and once authenticate shows the main window.

Comment: Usually you use runmodal with dialogs. The main window uses the main run loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run your main view in modal, modal should be used for dialogs. So you can run login view in modal (and finish it by calling `stopModal` on the application). In that case you could use smth like `loadLoginView` which will have similar implementation to your current `loadMainView` (but without this `self.view.window?.close()` call. And main view would be loaded from nib on application launch. But you have to post some more code (how your app initalization looks like?) to get help on that.